# Transferring 1 row of numbers from excel to R

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to transfer a row of numbers from excel to R.
The idea is to put the numbers into a vector and compare it with another vector in order to find differences between them.

I have assembled all numbers along a single row with each placed in their own box. But as i try to copy paste it into a vector in R it appears not to contain all the numbers from the excel arc.

The row contains a substantial amount of numbers so i reckon it has something to do with the capacity of the vector. Is there perhaps a different method of succesfully transfering my numbers from excel to R?

Comment: Save as a csv file? I would be surprised if the issue is one of the capacity of r vectors (which can have over a million elements).

Comment: Have you tried the readxl package? ([link](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl))

Comment: I think I found the issue. I have placed the numbers as following, in the Excel document:

Example: “122345-2054”, “436587-2306”, 235678-9385”,. Etc

They are each placed in their own column.

I then tried to save the Excel file as an cvs file in the hopes of loading it successfully into R.

I then used the following command in R in order to load the file into the program:

data.x<-read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)
but when I then use the command: data.x it just says:
0 rows> (or 0-length ro.name)

What could I possibly do to correct this?

Thank you for the previous replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying and pasting as string and then using a function like strsplit() to split your string into a long vector, and then convert it into numeric. Here is an example code with steps:

step 1: (In excel) Remove all commas, and non-numeric characters, you can keep decimals.
step 2: (In excel) Copy the entire row in excel.
step 3: (In R)

```
    number <- readClipboard(format = 1)    
    number <- strsplit(number, "\t")[[1]]  
    number <- strsplit(number, "-")
    final <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(number)), nrow = length(number), byrow = TRUE)
```

You should end up with two columns. Col 1 will be all the numbers in each cell preceding the '-' and Col 2 will be all the numbers in each cell succeeding the '-'.